# Why do unordered_set operations like count and erase return a size_type?

Tags: c++, hashset, std, unordered-set

Apparently, [`unordered_set::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase) and [`unordered_set::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count) return something that is not strictly boolean (logically, that is, I'm not talking about the actual type).

The linked page reads for the third version of erase:

```
size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

> Removes the elements with the key value key

This has a tone to it that suggests there could be more than just one element with a given key. It doesn't explicitly state this, but it sounds like it a lot.
Now, the point of a set, even an unordered one, is to have each element once.

The standard library acknowledges the existence of the `bool` type and uses it for boolean values like [`unordered_set::empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/empty). **So, what's the point of returning `size_type` in the cases above? Even in spite of hash collisions, the container should distinguish elements with different keys, right? Can I still rely on that?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a.erase(k) size_type Erases all elements with key
>                       equivalent to k. Returns the
>                      number of elements erased.
>
> b.count(k) size_type  Returns the number of elements with key
>   equivalent to k.

It's because of the [unordered associative container requirements](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) [23.2.5].

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked the source of this quote.

Comment: Thanks. Just a small nit pick: That section seems to refer to {multi}{set,map} only. The unordered counterparts are in 23.2.5.

Comment: The unordered requirements should be effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just so that they could re-use the wording from `unordered_multiset`. You don't have to worry about hash collisions except for performance-wise, the container is still correct even if every element collides- even if such a thing would be stupendously slow.

Comment: Even though I expected as much, it is still comforting to hear it.